# bpf vs ebpf communication between kernel space and user space

Tags: kernel, ebpf

Does bpf allow just passing data from kernel space to user space ? Or there is a way to pass data from user space to kernel space without using ebpf?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Do you mean to ask how eBPF maps (for storing and passing data between kernel and user space, in the two directions) work? Or do you refer to “passing data” as filtering data on a socket? What use case do you have in mind?

Comment: The first one. I mean is just a feature of eBPF or also of BPF? Do you know a good source which teach how to write simple programs in eBPF/BPF ?

Comment: The maps (hash tables, arrays, or other key/value structures) are an eBPF-only feature (not supported by “classic” BPF as used by tcpdump or seccomp) and can pass data both directions.
I'd suggest having a look at existing samples ([kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf), [Netronome's](https://github.com/Netronome/bpf-samples/)), at this [list of resources](https://github.com/zoidbergwill/awesome-ebpf#articles-and-presentations), or for more details, at [Cilium reference documentation](http://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/bpf/) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks a lotl. So BPF can pass data in just one direction right?

Comment: Classic BPF (cBPF) does not use maps, and has no alternative mechanism to pass or get data from user space. So there is no data passing at all (unless I misunderstood your question?). With maps, the newer eBPF can pass both directions.

Comment: I mean can't I pass cBPF program from user space to kernel space? or I can just with eBPF

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand “data” meant “programs” in your case. All of BPF (cBPF/eBPF) rely on injecting user programs to kernel space. (However I don't see what you mean by “passing programs” in the other direction, from kernel to user space, you can retrieve BPF programs previously loaded to e.g. dump them in user space, if that's what you mean.)